# Hatafas Dam Bris-Performed

Tags: how-to, brit-milah

How does one perform a Hatafas Dam Bris?  What are all the steps in the process?  Additionally, what Brachos (if any) are made at a Hatafas Dam Bris?

Comment: Its a poke in the skin where the foreskin used to be or normally is attached. Google what is hatafat dam brit. A diabetic lance seems to be the preferred  tool.

Comment: I did a geirut misafek and they drew blood from two places, the glans and the shaft which involved going through the foreskinlike tissue and into the organ. The two drawings may be a stringency. A syringe was used to draw the blood, I believe.

Answer (score 2):

1. If a child was born circumcise,  there is a controversy between Rishonim and Geonim if he needs hatafat dam berit ,  or nothing (see in Tur YD 263).  Halacha lemaase the hatafa itself needs no Beracha, but after the hatafa we say the standard beracha "lehachnisso,  asher kiddesh yedid mibbeten..." (The opinion of the Baal Hayitur was that the hatafa itself needs a special bracha as a mila-analogue.)
2. For a convert *who is not born "circumcised" but was circumcised before his conversion,*  some opinions (Baal Halachot Gedolot)  says that he can no more be circumcised and there is nothing to do and some else opinion  (Rif, Rambam) says that he needs hatafat dam berit. This hatafa needs to be made carefully without damaging (Tur YD 263). The hatafa itself needs no Beracha. The  beracha, said after the hatafa   is  different for a convert. in **Tur YD 268**  the nusach is:

   > ברוך אתה יי אלהינו מלך העולם, אשר קדשנו במצותיו וצונו למול את הגרים ולהטיף מהם דם ברית, שאלמלא דם ברית לא נתקיימו שמים וארץ, שנאמר אם לא בריתי יומם ולילה, חוקות שמים וארץ לא שמתי", וחותם: "ברוך אתה יי, כורת הברית". ולדברי האומר שמברכים שתים על העבדים – גם על הגרים מברכים שתים.‏
3. It is  interesting to note that the hatafat dam berit is mentioned in the nuscha for the convert. The Baer Heytev in name of the Perisha adds that the end of this Beracha is Koret Haberit as for a Jewish man.

note: **But there is no Birkat  "al hamila"**  (it is almost  obvious) as written in SA YD 265,  3:

**Additional explanation**

This beracha is said after the hatafa or after the mila,  there is no problem of over leassiatan because the blesser is not the mohel (Rabenu Tam) or because it is a blessing of praise (Ran),  not linked to the actual  act of mila.

For the practice I am not mohel,  but it seems to be easy to find a blood vessel and to generate a bleeding.

Answer (score -1):

**How does one perform a Hatafas Dam Bris?**
origin from - http://www.mayyimhayyim.org/using-the-mikveh/the-process-of-conversion
*Circumcision / Hatafat Dam Brit
Ritual circumcision is a sign of the covenant between each individual man and the people of Israel. For men who have already been medically circumcised, this ritual involves the drawing of a drop of blood, hatafat dam brit, which is usually performed by a mohel, one who is trained in this practice and recites a blessing as he/she performs it. Your rabbi should be able to answer questions about this practice and will either engage or refer you to a mohel.*

> Additionally, what Brachos (if any) are made at a Hatafas Dam Bris?
>   answer see - https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3h4gF38y-sYaU9NSXBHYUczYVE/view

Comment: This says "see your rabbi" for half the question and "see this Web site" for the other half. Thus, it doesn't actually answer the question. See http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/2187